# Pass a 2d array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, graph, multidimensional-array

I deal with graphs more often than not and find it difficult to pass the adjacency list to a function.

```
void myfunc(int ad[][])//proper way to receive it?
{
}

int main()
{
    int N;//number of vertices
    cin >> N;
    int ad[N][N];
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<N;j++)
            cin >> ad[i][j];
    myfunc(ad); //proper way to pass it?
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if this is a noob question but I found people passing 2d arrays which had fixed and known dimensions only. No idea how to do this.

Comment: You CAN'T declare `int ad[N][N];` when N is not constant.

Comment: @user2316393 That's because it's an extension of the compiler you're using. [Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) were supposed to be in the latest C++14 standard, but was removed so it's still not in the C++ language.

Comment: So what's the alternative? How do I use a 2-d array of a size decided at run time and pass it to a function?

Comment: The alternative is [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Well I knew about vector and did use it. But just wanted to know if it could be done with arrays. Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable length array (VLA) is not standard in C++.

Use `std::vector` instead:

```
void myfunc(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& ad)
{
}

int main()
{
    int N;//number of vertices
    cin >> N;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> ad(N, std::vector<int>(N));
    for(int i = 0; i<N; i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<N;j++)
            cin >> ad[i][j];
    myfunc(ad);
}
```